# A theorem about ideals of $K[T_1,\ldots,T_n]$ and their generators

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, polynomials, ideals, extension-field

Suppose that $L\subseteq K$ is a field extension ( we are in characteristic $0$) and moreover that $\mathfrak a\subseteq K[T_1,\ldots,T_n]$  is an ideal ($T_1,\ldots,T_n$ are indeterminates).

I have heard that there exists the following theorem:

> **Theorem:** There exists a unique subfield $K_0$ between $L$ and $K$ with the
> following properties:
>
> 1. $\mathfrak a$ is generated by some polynomials with coefficients in $K_0$.
> 2. If $k$ is any field between $L$ and $K$  such that $\mathfrak a$ is generated by some polynomials with coefficients in $k$, then
>    $k\supseteq K_0$.

I need any kind of reference for the proof of this theorem because I can't find it. Also suggestions for a direct proof are welcome.

**Addendum:** If $\mathfrak a$ is homogeneous, can I find a set of homogeneous generators in $K_0$?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The addendum follows easily from the general case, as the homogeneous components of an element of an homogeneous ideal $a$ are themselves elements of $a$.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT** Suppose $M \subset K$ is a subfield of $K$. Then we can consider $\mathfrak a \cap M[T_1, \cdots,T_n]$. This is an ideal $\mathfrak b$ in $M[T_1, \cdots, T_n]$. Now let $\mathfrak b \otimes K$ be the ideal generated by $\mathfrak b$ in $K[T_1, \cdots, T_n]$. If $\mathfrak b \otimes K = \mathfrak a$, call $M$ an **admissible** subfield $K$. Then take the intersection of all admissible subfields of $K$.

Then 1. is clear, and 2. also.

Note that you are not anywhere referring too $L$ in the statement of the theorem.

Comment: The field generated by the coefficients of the polynomials in $a$ is always $K$, except if $a = (0)$. Even if you'd take a (finite) set of generators of $a$, you can't take $K_0$ to be the field generated by the coefficients of those generators: not every set of generators gives the same $K_0$.

Comment: @Magdiragdag Thank you, you are of course right. I've changed my answer. Does this look correct?

Comment: I think you need that the intersection of admissible subfields is admissible again. This doesn't seem immediately obvious to me.

Comment: @Magdiragdag, yes this is the point! I don't understand the same thing. Sorry for the deleted comment.

Comment: @Magdiragdag Good point! I'll have to think about it.

Comment: maybe this can be intresting: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/110939/origin-of-the-theorem-on-the-existence-of-the-smallest-field-of-definition-of-an

Comment: @fair-cointossing Nice find. And the comment by Markus Schweighofer there actually proves the statement. This seems much more involved than I expected, although Schweighofer's argument using Grobner basis is very short and neat.

Comment: However a longer, but simpler proof can be found in "Lang - Introduction to ALgebraic Geometry" at page 62, theorem 7